# INSERT INTO with joins?

Tags: mysql, join, insert

I got trouble inserting data to a table that has joins to other tables, I've never done that before and the searchs I went through didn't help much.

I have an article page with a "comment" form that I want to send to my "**comment**" table. The "comment" table has joins with my "**user**" and "**article**" tables (to get which article the comment is part of, and which user sent it)

My comment table columns : **comment_id, article_id, author_id, submitted_at, content**

My user table columns : 
**user_id, username, password**

My article table columns : **article_id, preview_image, title, description, body, publishedAt, author_id**

So this is what my query looks like :

```
    public function setComment() {
    try{
    $stmt = $this->connection()->prepare("INSERT INTO comment (article_id, author_id, submitted_at, content) (SELECT comment.article_id, comment.author_id, submitted_at, content 
    FROM comment INNER JOIN user ON comment.author_id = user.user_id INNER JOIN article ON comment.article_id = article.article_id)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':article_id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':author_id', $_GET['id'],  PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':content', $_POST['comment'],  PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Well there is no error.... the only problem here is, when I submit my form all my rows in the **comment** table are duplicated by 2 lol... I just want to add a new row with the data in my bindParam()

So what's wrong?

BY THE WAY during my searchs I've seen people don't specify VALUE() when inserting to a table that has joins. So how do I insert the data that are in my bindParam()? That's weird

---

EDIT :: **FOUND IT!!** Actually I didn't need to use a SELECT at all

The correct query was :

```
INSERT INTO comment (article_id, author_id, submitted_at, content) 
VALUES (:article_id, :author_id, NOW(), :content)
```

I had an error telling me "*SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails*"... So I thought I needed to join the tables or something but the actual problem was because in my query I bound the author_id to $_GET['id'] (that was 9)... and there is no user with the id of 9 in my user table. Shame on me

I used $_GET['id'] because I don't know how to properly get the id of the user sending the comment (and bindParam doesn't like it when I just use an integer)... with the session maybe idk, but that's a problem for another time

Comment: If you execute the `select` part, without the `insert` part, but with the same parameters, how many rows do you get? Anyway, the bound parameters are nowhere used in the query...

Comment: @ZorgoZ Yes but how do I use them in the query? I actually don't get the syntax for inserting stuff with a table that has joins...

From what I've seen people use "INSERT INTO" with "SELECT" afterward and don't use the VALUE() so i'm confused on how I'm supposed to send my parameters to the query

Comment: Just because it is syntactically correct, does not mean that it does what you want. Have you looked at this documentation page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php ? If you are using named placeholders, you can/should use them in the query, like this: `INSERT INTO comment (article_id, author_id, submitted_at, content) values (:article_id, :author_id, NOW() ,:comment)`. And I really don't see why you need that `select` part at all...

Comment: The fact that you have all the other tables in some relation with the comment table does not mean at all that you need them in a DML statement. You _might_ need some of the relations in a SELECT query statement that you can express with JOINs, but rarely in a DML.

Comment: You can combine DML with a SELECT, but only if it is needed - again: rarely. You seem not to actually understand the SQL standard related languages. I suggest you look for a tutoria.

Comment: You might need to use a `SELECT` if you have the username in a variable, but want to put the user ID into the `comments` table. But there doesn't seem to be a need for `SELECT` in your actual use case.

Comment: Thing is when I just use "INSERT INTO comment (article_id, author_id, submitted_at, content) VALUES (:article_id, :author_id, NOW(), :content)" I get the error "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" because there is relation between my comment table and two others... And to join the other tables, I saw that you need to get them with the usual SELECT blabla JOIN blabla... I just don't get the correct syntax... but maybe I'm wrong and I don't need that at all idk

Comment: If you're getting that error, it means you need to insert the corresponding rows into the `user` and `article` tables before you try to insert into the `comment` table. It seems like you're expecting the join to insert into all the tables, that's not how it works.

Comment: Thanks guys it works lol read the edit of my post. I'm actually a dumb ass